# How to access functions inside struct in C#

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{ 
   public  struct course
   {
        public string name;
        public int elecode;
        public int credit;


        public static void getdetails()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your Name");
           Ele.name = Console.ReadLine();

        }
   }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        course ele;
        ele.getdetails();

    }
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx

Comment: Unless you really understand the differences between `struct` and `class` in C#, one should generally stick with `class`.

Comment: I know that has nothing to do with the question but i would still suggest that you read through the naming guidlines https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Your method `getdetails` should not be static
2. Remove `Ele.` inside `getdetails`
3. Initialize `course ele` variable

Your code:

```
class Program
{ 
   public  struct course
   {
        public string name;
        public void getdetails()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your Name");
            name = Console.ReadLine();
        }
   }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {    
        course ele = new course();
        ele.getdetails();
    }
}
```

As was mentioned by @DavidHeffernan in comment about poor design, you have to know where to use `class` instead of `struct` to escape problems, when [a value type gives you a COPY of the value](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/05/14/mutating-readonly-structs/)

Comment: Mutating the struct by a method call is poor design

Comment: Thanks, mentioned about that in the answer

Answer (score 4):

You can not call static method with instance. You have static method so call it with struct instead of calling it with the instance of struct.

```
course.getdetails();
```

> The static member is callable on a class even when no instance of the
>   class has been created. The static member is always accessed by the
>   class name, not the instance name

Read more about static on this MSDN article [Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx).